# How to style pills in a Word document?

Tags: ms-word

In an MS Word document, how can I style text into pills, for example like the Bootstrap pills or in the image below?

Doesn't have to be exactly like this, just something similar.

I can highlight a word but it is very limited.

Apologies if this is off topic.  I could find a better location.

[image: pills]

Additionally, I would rather keep the elements within the flow of the page, so that it can scraped correctly by CV scanners.
I.E. I don't want to insert a load of floating textboxes.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. As such it is off-topic for StackOverflow and should be asked in an appropriate end-user forum.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of range.border and font properties

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakePill(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range)

    ' Ensure a space before and after the text in the range
    myRange.InsertBefore Text:=" "
    ipRange.InsertAfter Text:=" "
    myRange.Borders.Enable = True
    myRange.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAqua


End Sub
```

Comment: What language is this?  VBA?

Comment: Yes, VBA is the native scripting language for ms-word.